# Cotensor vs exponential objects.

Tags: ct.category-theory, enriched-category-theory

Under which conditions can we say that the cotensor objects in a (closed) V-category are the exponential objects? It is just when V=Set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this happens more often.  Let me write $A\odot X$ and $X^A$ for tensors and cotensors in a category enriched over $\mathcal{V}$. I think you are (or might be) asking for a (natural) isomorphism between $A\odot X$ and $X^A$.  In many algebraic situations, it is sensible to write $A\otimes X$ and $Hom(A,X)$.  Writing $DA = Hom(A,k)$ in $\mathcal V$, where $k$ is the unit object of $\mathcal V$, it is then sometimes true that $Hom(A,X)$ is isomorphic to $DA\otimes X$. It is also sometimes true that $A$ is isomorphic to $DA$.  That is true more often than it is true naturally, but if $\mathcal V$ is finite dimensional inner product spaces over the reals, for example, then there is a kind of contravariant naturality.  This is not a complete answer of course, but it should give you a way to think about examples.

Comment: Thanks. Did you mean perhaps Hom(A,X) iso DAtensorX?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Are your "many algebraic situations" just abelian categories or do you have experience of cotensors in other settings? I am thinking of the category of algebras for some strong monad over $\mathcal V$.

Comment: I rarely deal with abelian categories.  I'm thinking for example of self-dual
objects in symmetric monoidal categories, such as orbit $G$-spectra for
a finite group $G$.   Fausk, Hu, and I wrote a general categorical study
of situations where left and right adjoints are isomorphic: http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/PAPERS/FormalFinalMarch.pdf